# Add animation to default marker on setOnMarkerClickListener maps api v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am developing an android app, which have fragment containing a Mapview...
The mapview containing markers according to the locations in the local database..
is there any way to animate or even change the colour of only clicked marker?
I mean i have done it in setOnMarkerClickListener, but, when i click on the another marker, the previous marker still in the same color/animation...

Adding the main part of the code below...

```
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("Select * from location", null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                id = c.getInt(0);
                if (userPrefs.getString("locale",null)==null || userPrefs.getString("locale",null).equals("en"))
                {
                    storename = c.getString(1);
                }
                else {
                    storename = c.getString(7);
                }
                stlatitude = c.getDouble(2);
                stlongitude = c.getDouble(3);
                city = c.getString(4);
                String emirate = c.getString(5);
                storeloc = new Location("StoreLocation");
                storeloc.setLatitude(stlatitude);
                storeloc.setLongitude(stlongitude);
                addmarker();
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    myDataBase.close();

    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String s= marker.getTitle();
            String snippet= marker.getSnippet();
            markerlat= marker.getPosition().latitude;
            markerlong= marker.getPosition().longitude;
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            tv.setText(s);
            tv1.setText(snippet);
                if (s.equals(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.here))) {
                    if (relbutton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && reltext.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        relbutton.setAlpha(1.0f);
                        relbutton.animate().translationY(0).alpha(0.0f);
                        relbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (relbutton.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE && reltext.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                        reltext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        reltext.setAlpha(0.0f);
                        reltext.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f);
                        if (userPrefs.getString("locale",null).equals("ar"))
                        {
                            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
                            relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                            RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
                            relativeLayout1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        }
                    }

                } else if (relbutton.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE && reltext.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    relbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    reltext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    reltext.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    reltext.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f);
                    relbutton.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    relbutton.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f);
                    if (userPrefs.getString("locale",null).equals("ar"))
                    {
                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
                        relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
                        relativeLayout1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    }
                } else if (reltext.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    relbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    relbutton.setAlpha(0.0f);
                    relbutton.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f);
                    if (userPrefs.getString("locale",null).equals("ar"))
                    {
                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
                        relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
                        relativeLayout1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    }
                }
            return true;
        }

    });


    directions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nwLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if(nwLocation!=null) {
                userlatitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
                userlongitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();
            if(markerlat!=null && markerlong!=null) {
                String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=" + userlatitude + "," + userlongitude + "&daddr=" + markerlat + "," + markerlong;
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            }
            else {
                showSettingsAlert("NETWORK");
            }
        }
    });
    return  view;
}

private void addmarker() {
    markerOptions.position(new LatLng(stlatitude, stlongitude));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
    markerOptions.title(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.xpressionsstyle));
    markerOptions.snippet(storename);
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Comment: How many marker you want to draw on the map screen??

Comment: as much as the number of locations in the database...

Comment: All maker should in different colours ??

Comment: nop... in same color except the user location marker and selected marker...

Comment: My solution worked or not??

Comment: wait.. let me check...

Comment: oks...take yours time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out the solution by changing the onmarkerclick code as below...

```
  public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            String s= marker.getTitle();
            String snippet= marker.getSnippet();
            markerlat= marker.getPosition().latitude;
            markerlong= marker.getPosition().longitude;
            if(prevmarker!=null){
                    if(!prevmarker.getTitle().equals(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.here)))
                {
                    prevmarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
                }
            }
            if (!s.equals(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.here))) {
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the arraylist with different colors name like
In oncreateView use these lines..

**And maintain value of integer int color_value =0;**
    And increment these value on marker click event;

```
int color_value = 0;
ArrayList<String> colours = new ArrayList<String>();
colours.add("HUE_RED");
colours.add("HUE_BLACK");
colours.add("HUE_BLUE");
colours.add("HUE_PINK");
colours.add("HUE_GRAY");
colours.add("HUE_YELLOW");
.
.
.
.
.
colours.add("HUE_GREEN");
```

and than onMarkerClickListener use following lines of code and incremnt the value of color_value;

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
for(int i =0;i<=colours.size();i++)
 {  
  if(color_value==i)
   {
    if(color_value==colours.size)
     {
      colur_value=0;
     }
     else
     {
      color_value++;//increment the value of color from here
     }
             marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.colours.get(i)));

 break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: this is not the thing am trying to explain... I need only change the color of the selected marker... if the user select another marker, the color of the previous marker should reset to the default color...

Comment: It is also possible..Whenever you click to mark the marker than you have to remove previous maker and in place of it,you have to put the different type of colour of marker..

Answer (score 0):

first define marker on oncreate like this

makerDefault = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_default);

After that use this  class
 private class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

```
        private List<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

        public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        }

        public void addOverlayItem(int lat, int lon, String title, Drawable altMarker) {

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, null);
            addOverlayItem(overlayItem, altMarker);
        }

        public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
            mOverlays.add(overlayItem);
            populate();
        }

        public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem, Drawable altMarker) {
            overlayItem.setMarker(boundCenterBottom(altMarker));
            addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return mOverlays.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() 
        {
            return mOverlays.size();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
           // Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, getItem(index).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(LocationActivity.this, PlaceOrderActivity.class);              
            intent.putExtra("shop_no", getItem(index).getTitle());


            startActivity(intent);  
            return true;
        }

    }
```

after that bind your data like this
MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(makerDefault);

```
                       JSONArray array=     new JSONArray(data);
                       String da=String.valueOf(array.length());
                       Log.d("da", da);
                         for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                             JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                             Log.d("jsonObject", jsonObject.toString());
                             shopname=jsonObject.getString("0");                                                            
                             latitude=jsonObject.getString("1");
                             longitude=jsonObject.getString("2");
                             shop_no=jsonObject.getString("3");
                             Log.d("shopname", shopname);

                                mc = mapView.getController();                               
                                double dbl_latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                                int Lat = (int)(dbl_latitude * 1E6);                                                            
                                double dbl_longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                                int Lon = (int)(dbl_longitude* 1E6);

                                itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(Lat, Lon, shop_no, makerDefault);
                                 mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
                                mc.setCenter(new GeoPoint(Lat, Lon)); 
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Lat+""+Lon, 3000).show();
                                mc.zoomToSpan(itemizedOverlay.getLatSpanE6(), itemizedOverlay.getLonSpanE6());
```

in this you have to put multiple image with your desire color